# Why is Wordpress enqueuing admin relevant scripts (e.g., React, ReactDOM, Redux, hooks, TinyMCE etc) when not logged in?

Tags: wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-script

In attempting to boost the performance of my website, I've noticed that Wordpress is enqueuing a lot of the admin relevant scripts and stylesheets on the front end.

I'm wondering how I can stop this from happening...I was thinking about dequeueing all of the offending, but then my server response time would be slightly slowed.

Is there a tried and tested way of doing this?

Comment: The only scripts that should be enqueued from the front-end are `/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js` and `/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js`. If other scripts are enqueued, something in your theme or plugins must be doing this.

Comment: Yeh, I think that's kind of what I'm asking. i.e., how to stop this behaviour. It's a custom theme, and haven't set anything up in place. I have everything that is available when logged in available when not and on the front end...

Comment: @MikeNGarrett Very minimal amount of plugins installed, mainly just using ACF. Wordpress version is the latest version as well, as of today. It's not a bug is it?

Comment: Just to make sure, are you looking at the front-end as a logged-in user or are you totally logged out?

Comment: @MikeNGarrett Totally logged out...my enqueue.php file is very minimal. Only using scripts and styles I need.

Comment: This is not normal WordPress core behavior. Can you provide some additional details about the scripts and styles you're enqueuing and the urls you're seeing included from the front-end?

Comment: @MikeNGarrett I must add my functions.php was an absolute fresh blank file when I started...is there something in Wordpress pre-built themes I'm missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92054/discussion-between-wind-up-lord-vexxos-and-mikengarrett).

Comment: @MikeNGarrett Hi Mike - your suggestion of changing the naming conventions of the enqueued scripts and styles worked, so there must have been something non-unique in the names of one of these that was causing a conflict. Obvious when I think about it. Wordpress 101. If you answer with this, I can accept. Many thanks if you don't have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bootstrap or other enqueued scripts have a dependency or name conflict, this could enqueue all these scripts. There are a [large number of common scripts in WordPress core](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#default-scripts-included-and-registered-by-wordpress) that are enqueued under common names. I always recommend prefixing your script names with something specific.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-bootstrap', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '4.3.1', true );
```

Comment: Yeh, I made the rookie mistake of not prepending the enqueued script names with the theme name. Will never make this mistake again.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!